# Is there any way to read from one Netty channel only as fast as you can write to another?

Tags: java, netty

We're experiencing an issue in LittleProxy where OutOfMemoryErrors are popping up when reading from a fast server LittleProxy is proxying access to and writing to a slow client configured to use the proxy. The problem is that the data coming in from the server buffers up in memory faster than we can write it to the client. LittleProxy is just a simple HTTP proxy built atop Netty.

Is there any easy way to throttle the read from the remote server to be exactly the same speed as the client is able to read it?

See:

https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy/issues/53

and

https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy

Comment: why not just pause reading from the server?

Comment: The discussion here may help you: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/netty/Zz4enelRwYE

Comment: @irreputable Sure, you could do that, but it would be a bit crude. Ideally we'd read from the server at exactly the same rate as the client is reading from us. Just pausing periodically would be pretty clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at source code of : org.jboss.netty.example.proxy.HexDumpProxyInboundHandler
It set the inbound channel readeable flag according to outbound channel's status. Hope this could help.

Comment: Yup that should do it. Going to implement and test the fix before marking it as the answer, but definitely looks right.

Comment: A variation on that technique worked great -- thanks @Jian Jin!!